Can't sync time on Windows 10 due to w32tm access denied
tl;dr: I cannot sync time on Windows 10, because w32tm /resync responds with Access denied. The strangest (to me) part is that I can run w32tm in combination with any other switch. It says about no access only when used with /resync switch. What should I do in this case?

(sorry for screenshots in Polish; doing anything as administrator)
Time sync in Windows 10 fails in Settings application with error that time synchronization has failed:

This is a newer screenshot, when (one-time? somehow?) I managed to synchronize time. Previously the second line was saying that there is not time server defined.
Based on this article and this one I have tried to set the time server:
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:time.nist.gov
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:time.windows.com
w32tm /config /update

And I have got:
The command completed successfully

in each case. I also can run w32tm /register and w32tm /unregister with no errors.
But running w32tm /resync for the first time ended up with:
The following error occurred: Service is not running (0x80070426)

Based on that, I have checked Windows services and to my surprise I have found Windows Time service both turned-off and set to manual start.
On contrary to this answer, I managed to start it up and set it to automatic startup without any problems:

Having Windows Time service up and running I have tried to run w32tm /resync again, but this time it ended up with:
Sending resync command to local computer
The following error occured: Access denied (0x80070005)

Here is a sequence screenshot (again, sorry for Polish):

Is there anything else that I can do, except for setting time manually next time it gets out-of-sync?

Try this procedure and let me know if it helps (or not).

Is this computer owned and managed by your employer or school, or is it a personal device that you fully own and control?

@harrymc I own and control device in question (I am an admin, this is not a PDC, however, it is semi-controlled by Microsoft Family, as it is used by my daughter). But, currently I have no physical access to it, so I'll report when this is checked. BTW: your source article says about "issue where all w32tm commands were failing". In my case /resync only fails. All other are working great. I don't know, if that matters.

The link describes a more robust method to reset the times and also the registry items that should have been set if the it succeeds. The information, even if it didn't help, could be useful in locating the problem.
